# uniq on 3 columns and retain the lines based on fourth column in linux/unix

Tags: sorting, unix, uniq

I have some data with four columns each and I want to keep the unique lines based on only the first 3 columns and retain their respective fourth column of maximum value also.

My data looks looks like the following:

```
chr1    5   10  1.5
chr1    5   10  0.1
chr3    7   15  5
chr3    7   15  2
chr8    10  20  3
```

Could you please assist me on achieving this? I need the output to look like the following:

```
chr1    5   10  1.5
chr3    7   15  5
chr8    10  20  3
```

Comment: You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Did you experiment with `sort -k*n* -u` or `uniq -f*n*` ? Good luck.

Comment: No code, no information on language (ksh, bash etc etc), OS and i can keep on going. Make your question complete if you want someone to take off some time in order to help you

Comment: I did tried with sort and uniq but it is not giving the desired output. sort -u -t \t -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 and it gives simply the sorted output and not removing the duplicates based on first 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough with `sort` only.

```
sort -k1,3 -u -t' ' input.txt
```

`-k` for sorting on the basis of column 1 to 3

`-u` for uniq

`-t` for delimiter

Comment: It is not giving the output as I shown and simply sorting the data.

Comment: @NareshDJ - Here I assume delimiter as `' '(one space)`. It works with that,  check it or change delimiter according to your need.

Comment: Yes, I tried with \t tab separator but it gives just the sorted data. Did you get the output as I shown in the post? Thank you for your help.